# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm setting some routing to make an AJAX request to my create action in the reviews controller. I've included the correct rails URL in the form with the objects 'user' and 'movie'. When I click create it gives me the error
`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/7/movies/12")`.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Write Review</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <%= simple_form_for user_movie_create_review_path(@movie.user, @movie), remote: true do |f| %>
                <%= f.input :text, as: :text, input_html: {rows: 5, class: 'simple_form_review'}%>
                <%= f.button :submit, "Submit Review", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

resources :users do
    resources :movies do 
        post 'create_review', to: 'reviews#create'
    end
end
```

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :movie

    validates :content, presence: true
end
```

rake routes:

`user_movie_create_review POST  /users/:user_id/movies/:movie_id/create_review(.:format) reviews#create`

request:

```
Started POST "/users/7/movies/12" for ::1 at 2019-09-20 19:15:53 +0200
```

Comment: You can find the correct path with the command `rails routes`

Comment: That is the correct path.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: probably it uses the default `get` method, add `method: :post` to `simple_form_for`

Comment: No it does a post.

Comment: try this: `<%= simple_form_for :review, url: user_movie_create_review_path(@movie.user, @movie), remote: true do |f| %>`

Comment: Amazing it works! Why? Could you make an answer and try to explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass review object to `simple_form_for`:

```
<%= simple_form_for @review, url: user_movie_create_review_path(@movie.user, @movie), remote: true do |f| %>
  ..
<% end %>
```

Comment: I do have a model :/

Comment: @helloiamhere I thought you were going to do it without using the model :)

Comment: but this answer still works :) Let me know if you have a better one otherwise I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you for the help!